# Sony AOSP for Z5 compact

Tags: build, android-source, android-8.0-oreo, sony-xperia

I'd like to build Oreo for my Z5 compact (suzuran, e5823). I started the instructions of Sony on  [their dev site](https://developer.sonymobile.com/open-devices/aosp-build-instructions/how-to-build-aosp-oreo-for-unlocked-xperia-devices/).

Contrary to 7.0 and 6.0 at the time, when I'm prompted for the configuration, I cannot see my device.

```
Lunch menu... pick a combo:
 1. aosp_arm-eng
 2. aosp_arm64-eng
 3. aosp_mips-eng
 4. aosp_mips64-eng
 5. aosp_x86-eng
 6. aosp_x86_64-eng
 7. full_fugu-userdebug
 8. aosp_fugu-userdebug
 9. car_emu_arm64-userdebug
 10. car_emu_arm-userdebug
 11. car_emu_x86_64-userdebug
 12. car_emu_x86-userdebug
 13. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
 14. m_e_arm-userdebug
 15. m_e_mips64-eng
 16. m_e_mips-userdebug
 17. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
 18. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
 19. aosp_dragon-userdebug
 20. aosp_dragon-eng
 21. aosp_marlin-userdebug
 22. aosp_marlin_svelte-userdebug
 23. aosp_sailfish-userdebug
 24. aosp_angler-userdebug
 25. aosp_bullhead-userdebug
 26. aosp_bullhead_svelte-userdebug
 27. hikey-userdebug
 28. aosp_f8131-userdebug
 29. aosp_f8132-userdebug
 30. aosp_f8331-userdebug
 31. aosp_f8332-userdebug
 32. aosp_g8231-userdebug
 33. aosp_g8232-userdebug
 34. aosp_f5321-userdebug
 35. aosp_g8441-userdebug
 36. aosp_g8141-userdebug
 37. aosp_g8142-userdebug
 38. aosp_g8341-userdebug
 39. aosp_g8342-userdebug
 40. aosp_f5121-userdebug
 41. aosp_f5122-userdebug
 42. aosp_e2303-userdebug
 43. aosp_e2333-userdebug

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng]
```

I'm not sure if I can pick aosp_arm-eng, download binaries from sony for 7.0.1 and pray for the best.

I am to wait that they release a specific guide, or update their repos?

Comment: Did you use the specific repo checkout operation mentioned in the instructions?  If not, you likely have a *huge* porting task ahead of you.

Comment: I didn't, because there is none. For 7 and 6 there were specific instructions, patches to get and so on, but for this time there's nothing like that. It's quite confusing as it looks like purely building AOSP

Comment: Only specific step seems to be about sony local_manifests, and that's done